# How to add an object with multiple fields into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I'm fairly new to Java and I've been trying to add an object to an ArrayList storing the respective object type. However, there is a catch. I want to have an indefinite amount of objects added into the ArrayList. The length is based on the user input, so I can't define them beforehand and use .add() after initializing the fields.

This is the class in question. There are 4 private fields and public getters and setters (only two included for context):

```
public class Player {
private int id; // This will be unique for each player.
private int roundScore; // Score accumulated during a round, suspect to be reset if the player rolls a double.
private int bankScore; // Secured score of a player.
private String name;

public Player() {
   roundScore = 0;
   bankScore = 0;   
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And this is the method I tried to use to generate players (this method is in another class):

```
public void generatePlayers(int num) {
    Player dummyPlayer = new Player();
    List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        dummyPlayer.setID(i);
        System.out.println("\nWhat is the name of player " + i++ + "?"); 
        dummyPlayer.setName(sr.nextLine());
        System.out.println(dummyPlayer.getName() + ", welcome to the game!");
        playerList.add(dummyPlayer); // Oops, this is dumb.       
    }    
}
```

The idea was to create an instance of a player object called "dummyPlayer", store the variables into the object and add the object into the ArrayList. "Should be fine, right?" or so I thought before I realized I basically added multiple instances of the same object which will all change if I change one of them because referencing is a thing.

Is there a way to individually set the fields of each value in the array? I'm sorry if I missed something vital or asking something stupid. I tried to search other questions but they didn't quite click. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just create your `dummyPlayer` *inside* your loop, so that each player in your array is a different object.

Comment: Also a good idea to make name and id into constructor parameters, and make the fields final, as they should probably not ever change.

Comment: Creating dummyPlayer inside my loop worked wonders! Can't believe I didn't think of that, thank you. If you don't mind me asking, what do you mean by making my fields "final"? @tgdavies

Comment: @GhostCat Yep, that was really bad on my part.

Comment: Putting the final modifier into the declaration. When you do that, you HAVE to assign a value within the constructor though, and you cant have setter methods. Beyond that: any good java book explains that. Learning such things means: doing self research. Asking for explanations is quick, but it takes away the experience of you figuring things yourself. And that part is key when learning programming

Comment: You forget about scope. Like all the earlier comments, you have to simply create a new Object inside the for loop. This should be it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @tgdavies, change generatePlayers() to move the `new Player()` line inside the for loop like so:

```
public void generatePlayers(int num) {
    List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    Scanner sr = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        Player dummyPlayer = new Player();
        dummyPlayer.setID(i);
        System.out.println("\nWhat is the name of player " + i++ + "?"); 
        dummyPlayer.setName(sr.nextLine());
        System.out.println(dummyPlayer.getName() + ", welcome to the game!");
        playerList.add(dummyPlayer); // Oops, this is dumb.       
    }    
}
```

This way for every iteration of the for loop you create a new instance of `Player`, and you get to keep the as-is `dummyPlayer` variable (since local variables only exist within the block it is stated).

If for some reason there is a need to reference the  `dummyPlayer` variable outside the for loop, you can state just the type and variable name before the loop and instantiate the `Player` class in the loop:

```
    //... Same as above
    Player dummyPlayer; //beware of null
    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        dummyPlayer = new Player(); //Player class instantiation
        //... Same as above
    }
    
    dummyPlayer.toString();  //you can still reference dummyPlayer from here
```